# SP2013 - Call to display host web list data only works once

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I'm building a SP2013 App.

- I able to successfully pull back list data from the host web with with the following code that loads the "sharePointReadyToGetReviews()" function through an on-load event.
- My users will then be able to add to that list. The code functions to add a list item and then recalls this set of functions to reload the list.
- However I keep receiving the following error: `The Collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.`  when this line is reloaded:

  ```
   var enumerator = allSolutionReviews.getEnumerator();
  ```

the code is as follows:

```
    var web;
    var hostweburl;
    var appweburl;
    var collListItem;

function sharePointReadyToGetReviews() {
       hostweburl =
            decodeURIComponent(
                getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl')
        );
       appweburl =
           decodeURIComponent(
               getQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl')
        );

        var scriptbase = hostweburl + '/_layouts/15/';

        $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.Runtime.js',
            function () {
                $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.js',
                    function () { $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.RequestExecutor.js', returnReviews); }
                );
            }
        );
    }


    function getQueryStringParameter(param) {
        var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
        //var strParams = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
            var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
            if (singleParam[0] == param) {
                return singleParam[1];
            }
        }
    }

function returnReviews() {

$("#renderAnnouncements").empty();

    var context;
    var factory;
    var appContextSite;
    var oWebsite;

    context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
    appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl);    
    oWebsite = appContextSite.get_web();

    var list = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle("SolutionReviews"); 
    var camlString = 
        "<View><ViewFields>" + 
            "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" + 
            "<FieldRef Name='Created' />" + 
            "<FieldRef Name='Author' />" + 
            "<FieldRef Name='AverageRating' />" + 
        "</ViewFields></View>"; 

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery(); 
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(camlString); 
    var allSolutionReviews = list.getItems(camlQuery); 
    context.load(allSolutionReviews); 

    context.executeQueryAsync( 
        Function.createDelegate(this, getReviewSuccessHandler), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, getReviewErrorHandler) 
    ); 

function getReviewSuccessHandler(data, req) { 
    var enumerator = allSolutionReviews.getEnumerator(); 

    while (enumerator.moveNext()) { 
        var announcement = enumerator.get_current();
        var name = announcement.get_item("Author").get_lookupValue();
        var starHTML = "";
        var stars = announcement.get_item("AverageRating");
        for (var i=0;i<stars;i++)
            {
                starHTML += '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>';
            }

        //<img> url below must be updated dependant on the domain its in
        $(".reviews-list").append('<li class="review clearfix">' +
                                '<img src="https://heathehret-my.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx" alt="Reviewer Avatar" />' +
                                '<div class="review-container">'+
                                    '<strong class="reviewer-name">' + name + '</strong>'+
                                    '<span class="review-date">'+announcement.get_item("Created") +'</span>'+
                                    '<div class="rating">'+
                                        starHTML +
                                    '</div>'+
                                    '<p class="review-content">'+announcement.get_item("Title")+'</p>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</li>'); 
    } 

} 

function getReviewErrorHandler(data, error, errorMessage) { 
    document.getElementById("renderAnnouncements").innerText = 
        "Could not complete cross-domain call: " + 
        errorMessage; 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem. I was calling sharePointReadyToGetReviews() every time I wanted the list data. This means it was loading SP.Runtime.js, SP.js, and SP.RequestExecutor.js every time I tried to load the list even though they were already loaded. So after the first call I always call returnReviews() since the functions it need are already loaded.